# How to automate Entity Data Model Wizard in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, extensibility, nuget

I can use the Package Manager Console to write some Powershell and automate Visual Studio. I can start the process of adding a Entity Framework Data Model with this code:

```
$dte.ItemOperations.AddNewItem("Visual C#\Data\ADO.NET Entity Data Model", "Foo.edmx")
```

I want to to automate the EDM wizard that pops up next so my Powershell script can handle all the steps of adding an EF model to my project. How to I reference this Entity Data Model Wizard in code?

When I manually do this with the macro recorder in Visual Studio running, it will skip these wizard steps for the Entity Data Model Wizard. I was hoping that could show me how to reference it in code.

I want a set of Powershell commands to automate all the wizard steps for adding an EF model to my project. As I understand it, a nuget package can setup all the necessary parts with Powershell and my package will need to configure an Entity Framework model on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of automating the EDM wizard in Powershell, I can use the EdmGen.exe command line utility to perform the task in Powershell.

EdmGen.exe is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738546.aspx